# Save PDFDocument to CoreData as NSData (how to convert it to NSData?)

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

so this might be a trivial question, but I can't get it to work.
I want to save a `pdf file` to CoreData after I dropped it onto a view (using IOS' `Drag&Drop` feature)

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
        session.loadObjects(ofClass: ComicBookPDFDocument.self) { (pdfItems) in
            let items = pdfItems as! [ComicBookPDFDocument]

            // "Cannot assign value of type 'ComicBookPDFDocument' to type 'NSData?'"
            self.file.data = items[0]
        }
}
```

`ComicBookPDFDocument` just subclasses `PDFDocument` to make it conforming to `NSItemProviderReading`:

```
final class ComicBookPDFDocument: PDFDocument, NSItemProviderReading {

    public static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [kUTTypePDF as String]
    }

    public static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> ComicBookPDFDocument {
        return ComicBookPDFDocument(data: data)!
    }
}
```

However, I get this compiler error from XCode:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ComicBookPDFDocument' to type 'NSData?'

How can I save the pdf data from a `PDFDocument`? I couldn't find anything on the internet or the documentation.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I don't know how I missed that, but here it is:

```
items[0].dataRepresentation()
```

Comment: Please provide a little context to your answer.  I don't see any "`items`" in your original sample code above.  I am trying to do the same think and have no idea where I am supposed to use this magical line: `items[0].dataRepresentation()`

Comment: @HirsuteJim There actually is an items variable defined in the sample code of my question

Answer (score 0):

You do one thing,

Try to save PDF into the Document Directory and save its path in the Core-Data.

Here is the code to save to Document directory and fetch from document direcory

```
class PDCache: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = PDCache()

func saveData(obj: Data, fileName: String){

    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).pdf")
    do{
        try obj.write(to: filename, options: .atomic)
    } catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func getData(fileName: String) -> URL?{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).pdf")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filename.path){
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: filename.path)
    }
    return nil
}

private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
}
```

To save the data use this

```
    let data = Data()
    self.saveData(obj: data, fileName: "myPdfFile")
```

and to get the file url use this

```
let pdfUrl = self.getData(fileName: "myPdfFile")
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't explain how to get the `Data()` in the first place. That's my only problem. (Also, I found the answer: there's an attribute `dataRepresentation()`. See my answer above)